# attempting to create radio and label elements with forEach function

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a quiz app at the moment.

Right now I am at the stage of creating radio and label elements for each value of the array but I am obviously not doing something right because when I click on the button to call the click event it does not work, no radio buttons or labels append to the selected div.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

```js
var dude = [{
  question: "What is dudes's favourte color?",
  choices: ["blue", "yellow", "red", "green"],
  answer: 0
}, {
  question: "What is dudes's favourte movie?",
  choices: ["Scarface", "The Terminator", "Shawshank Redemption", "The Dark Knight"],
  answer: 3
}, {
  question: "What was dudes's first ever job role?",
  choices: ["Cleaner", "Store Assistant", "Sales", "Admin"],
  answer: 1
}]

var currentQuestion = 0;
var questionNumber = 1;

dude[currentQuestion].choices.forEach(function(value) {
  var radio = document.createElement("input");
  var label = document.createElement("label");
  radio.setAttribute("type", "radio");
  radio.setAttribute("name", "answer");
  radio.setAtrribute("value", value);
  label.setAtrribute("for", value);
  quizSectionDiv.appendChild(radio);
  quizSectionDiv.appendChild(label);
})
```

The for each method is sitting within a click event, which works for the other lines of code it holds

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to tell you what's going wrong. Consider making a jsfiddle to illustrate your issue.

Comment: There's enough information here to tell you what's going wrong, @jimmy118. See my answer and explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the typos:

```js
var dude = [
  {question: "What is dudes's favourte color?",choices: ["blue", "yellow", "red", "green"],answer: 0}
];
   
  let quizSectionDiv = document.querySelector('div#quizSectionDiv');

  var currentQuestion = 0;
  var questionNumber  = 1;

  dude[currentQuestion].choices.forEach(function(value){
    var radio = document.createElement("input");
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    radio.setAttribute("type", "radio");
    radio.setAttribute("name", "answer");
    radio.setAttribute("value", value); // typo here (fixed)

    /*
      for -> ID
    */
    //WRONG label.setAtrribute("for", value);
    /* So */
    let radioID = 'question-'+currentQuestion;
    radio.setAttribute('id', radioID) ;
    label.setAttribute("for", radioID); // typo here (fixed)
    label.innerHTML = value;

    quizSectionDiv.appendChild(radio);
    quizSectionDiv.appendChild(label);
  })
```

```html
<div id="quizSectionDiv"></div>
```

When you run into such a problem, and you haven't got some debugger, you can comments and ex-comments your code until you find where the problem happens.

Start with:

```js
var dude = [
  {question: "What is dudes's favourte color?",choices: ["blue", "yellow", "red", "green"],answer: 0 }
 ];
 
 let currentQuestion = 0 ;
 dude[currentQuestion].choices.forEach(function(value){
 console.log("value",value); // to check the value and the loop
//var radio = document.createElement("input");
//var label = document.createElement("label");
//radio.setAttribute("type", "radio");
//radio.setAttribute("name", "answer");
//radio.setAtrribute("value", value);
//label.setAtrribute("for", value);
//quizSectionDiv.appendChild(radio);
//quizSectionDiv.appendChild(label);
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important;top:0;}
```

And ex-comment:

```js
var dude = [
  {question: "What is dudes's favourte color?",choices: ["blue", "yellow", "red", "green"],answer: 0 }
 ];
 
 let currentQuestion = 0 ;
 dude[currentQuestion].choices.forEach(function(value){
 console.log("value",value); // to check the value and the loop
var radio = document.createElement("input");
var label = document.createElement("label");
radio.setAttribute("type", "radio");
//radio.setAttribute("name", "answer");
//radio.setAtrribute("value", value);
//label.setAtrribute("for", value);
//quizSectionDiv.appendChild(radio);
//quizSectionDiv.appendChild(label);
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important;top:0;}
```

Until:

```js
var dude = [
  {question: "What is dudes's favourte color?",choices: ["blue", "yellow", "red", "green"],answer: 0 }
 ];
 
 let currentQuestion = 0 ;
 dude[currentQuestion].choices.forEach(function(value){
 console.log("value",value); // to check the value and the loop
var radio = document.createElement("input");
var label = document.createElement("label");
radio.setAttribute("type", "radio");
radio.setAttribute("name", "answer");
radio.setAtrribute("value", value); // HERE
//label.setAtrribute("for", value);
//quizSectionDiv.appendChild(radio);
//quizSectionDiv.appendChild(label);
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important;top:0;}

/****


   WHEN YOU RUN THIS CODE SNIPPET, AN ERROR HAPPENS 
   
   AS EXPECTED
   ===========

   (READ THE ANSWER PLEASE)

  *****/
```

Ex-commenting the line marked "HERE", loop stop => you find an error

But remember: there's always at least two problems. So fix this one, and continue to find the next one (on the next line).

Comment: Thank you so much Phlcare, I really appreciate the help and the way you have explained yourself. Thanks for the helpful tip as well!